# "Attention Required" message while browsing sites

Tags: google-chrome, browsing, captcha

I use Google Chrome browser. Recently I'm seeing the "attention required" page more frequently, as shown in the following image.

[image: CAPTCHA screenshot]

It's asking me to select some images and prove that I'm not a robot. Recently its frequency has increased. What's causing it? Does the browser have anything to do with this? Or is it because of my ISP? Is there any way to stop it?

Comment: The "Attention Required" page is generated by CloudFlare, which is used by many websites. It seems there might be an issue at your IP address; make sure there isn't something on your network that's doing odd things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of behavior is usually programmed to happen when the remote system receives a lot of requests from your IP address.  Since ISPs do not allocate the same public IP to more than one customer at a time, except for mobile connection, it is most likely coming from something in your home.

If you don't notice the problem on other sites, you should contact the site to double-check with them why it happens.

Otherwise, if you're on a mobile connection, you could contact your provider to get a public IP, but they may refuse or charge more for it.  If it's not a mobile connection, then most likely one of your devices is doing a lot of requests to that site and you should look into that.  It could be caused by many things including spyware or simply your family using the site abundantly.

Comment: Ah! I use a broadband connection with shared IP(That's what they told me) and that connection is also inside a router used by 4 people. I guess that's what causing the problem then. Dedicated IP requires a lot of money :(

Comment: Oh and it's happening in many sites. not just one. Thanks for your answer.